# Publishing Velocity of Kalman Filtered Clusters

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, pcl, kalman, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I've segmented an incoming Point Cloud, applied an euclidian cluster extraction and then associated the data between frames combined with a Kalman filter.

Right now I'm publishing text markers above every object, containing the object id, x and y position.
I wanna publish the x and y velocity ( from the Kalman filter)  aswell , but I'm struggling to find out how.
In Line 780 - 785 I've tried to so so with a geometry:msgs::Twist Publisher, but it doesn't publish anything.

I would appreciate any suggestion and thank you in advance!

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/df38892e638591117145c15289919cfd

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300379/publishing-velocity-of-kalman-filtered-clusters/) by [th6262](https://answers.ros.org/users/36840/th6262/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2018-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've figured it out! It works with KF0.statePost.at(2) and
KF0.statePost.at(3). The result is PIXEL/second. That's why the values are so small! Now I need to figure out a way to convert it to something useful

---

Originally posted by [th6262](https://answers.ros.org/users/36840/th6262/) with karma: 50 on 2018-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0